# How to limit my query to get only 5 products per category?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, backend

Alright, hello guys, I'm struggling for a while with this problem so I will need your help.

So here is the problem I have database with more than 6000 products and I wanted to get some specific categories and their sub categories and only the products associated with them.

Here is a sample array that I have made that stores the categories (the key is the chosen category ID and the array value is all of the sub categories ID's).

```
  $products_categories = array(
        3 => [
            4, 5 , 6
        ],
        10 => [
            40, 30, 20
        ]
    );
```

And that's my eloquent query to get all of the products with those categories.

```
  $all_fetched_categories = array_merge(...$products_categories);

  if (!empty($products_categories)) {
        $products = Product::query();

        $products = $products->with([
            'media',

        ])
        ->active()
        ->top()
        ->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($all_fetched_categories) {
                $query->whereIn('shop_category_id', $all_fetched_categories);
            });

        $products = $products->get();
    }
```

So the question is, I will need only 5 products per main category. With the code that I provided I can't make logical limitation in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch categories using `whereIn` and then add `products` eager loading with `take(5)` filter. Like this

```
$total = 5;
$categories = Categories::with(['products' => function($query) use ($total){
                                $query->latest()->take($total);
                         },'products.media'])
                        ->whereIn('shop_category_id', $all_fetched_categories)
                        ->get()
```

Assuming you have categories id in `$all_fetched_categories`

Comment: With this way you will take five products overall for all of the categories, because Laravel makes one query for the categories and then another one for the products and then it maps all of the junk that it received. With this way you limit the products query to 5. Anyways I tried it, close call indeed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @gogbog you can add `latest` in that filter so that it will give you latest 5 products and you can use variable too instead 5. i have updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with database **group by** syntax.
Database **group by** returns single item from each group.

You need to use eloquent collection method ***groupBy()***.
By this method you can filter groups by whatever conditions you want.

[Laravel eloquent ***groupBy()*** method doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-groupby)